# Is there a dark/light Leanback theme?

Tags: android-tv, leanback

I'm starting an Android TV app and was hoping to prepare for the eventual support of dark mode, is there a `LeanBack` theme like the `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight`? or if not, what is the correct approach here?

Thanks,

Comment: struggling with the same here. Did you find a solution on this?

Comment: Nope, I didn't really much from leanback so I just used the material theme although I haven't tackled dark mode yet as I didn't find a way to set the tv on dark mode, maybe with the new android there is a way?